# Create a BalloonPopup with two buttons

Tags: carto, android, popup

I'm trying to create a BalloonPopup that has 2 different buttons or interactive elements, but I don't seem to manage a way to do this. The guide I'm following is here https://carto.com/developers/mobile-sdk/guides/vector-objects-on-map/#balloonpopup in the "Add a BalloonPopup" section.

I did manage to detect onClick events on the BalloonPopup setting a `setVectorElementEventListener` in the associated Layer. But I don't find a way of detecting which element inside of the BalloonPopup was clicked.

Basically what I want is to have 2 different buttons inside the Balloon, and then detect which of them has been clicked, so I can perform 2 different actions.

I could open an Android floating dialog, but it won't look as great as this would.

Any help will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting scenario!

I haven't really thought about two different buttons inside of a `BalloonPopup`. The thing is, there really isn't a single good answer to give, custom elements inside popups are a niche case. However, there's a pretty solid solution.

Your code seems to be Java, from the function you provided, I hope you don't mind that my answer is in Kotlin. Should be understandable enough.

Since you mentioned you managed to attach a vector element listener, I'm guessing you're aware of this function for getting the click position:

```
override fun onVectorElementClicked(clickInfo: VectorElementClickInfo?): Boolean {
}
```

Inside that function, you find the center of the balloonpopup and the click position, as follows:

```
val position = clickInfo.clickPos
val center = (clickInfo.vectorElement as BalloonPopup).bounds.center
```

You could find out which button was pressed by comparing the positions clicked, e.g. the left button was clicked, or the top button was clicked:

```
val isLeftOfCenter = position.x < center.x
val isBelowCenter = position.y < center.y
```

Comment: Mmm, that's pretty interesting. I actually tried something like that before writing my question. However, how could I set up the text of the 2 buttons? I can only add a title and a description to the BalloonPopup. If you could allow to pass 2 different texts to be displayed in 2 different colums and/or rows, then I imagine I could make it work that way. However, I imagine a bit more customizable and powerful way of building these Balloons, letting the user add Android Views. Like we can do with the AlertDialog class, that can be easily extended through inflating custom Layouts.

Comment: Alright, I've been able to play a little bit, and using the Title and the Description, as upper and lower buttons respectively, there's a possible workaround with this. Again, as I said earlier, and as you pointed out, it's not perfect, but it could do the trick. I believe I could even simulate the touch event, by changing the title or description color, at the moment of clicking them.

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Alright, great to hear you figured it out :)

Comment: Actually I thought I managed to handle both buttons, but it wasn't the case. It seems the clicked position is always above than the center. So I can't use it for upper/lower buttons, which was the only way of setting 2 distinct buttons (thanks to the title and description attributes). Could it be that the center of the ```BalloonPopup``` is actually placed in the dialog arrow, on the bottom of it? So it's not really the center of the dialog, but the marker position? It's strange that ```clickInfo.getVectorElement().getBounds()``` returns equal ```minX = maxX``` and ```minY = maxY```

Comment: You're right, I was mistaken. `Bounds` returns the root geometry of the object, a point. Internally, of course, the size is known, but there is no way API for it. So, your two buttons would have to be left and right in order to differentiate touches

Comment: I was digging in the CPP files and found some interesting information. It would be nice to have possibilities of extending some of these classes or have a bit more customizing capabilities within these classes (like BalloonPopup). The 2 buttons on the left and right could work in other scenarios, but I need to write the text (so the description/title were necessary for me in this case). Thank you anyway for yous assistance. It has been useful to know a bit more of the Carto API.